# How to check a date in python dataframe if its within certain range

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

| date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 13/08/2021 | 21/08/2021 |

In the above python dataframe, I have 2 columns date1 and date2. Need to check whether the date in column date1 is within +- 10days of the date in column date2. If yes it should return true, else false. In this case, it should return true.

Comment: Nice. Please show a [mcve]. A date can be any number of things, and you've shown be attempt whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.dt.days` *method* to find the difference between dates.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
  "date1": ['13/08/2021','19/08/2021','13/08/2021','23/08/2021','30/08/2021'],
  "date2": ['21/08/2021','30/08/2021','23/08/2021','14/08/2021','13/08/2021']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df[['date1','date2']] = df[['date1','date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime) 
df['days']  = (df['date2'] - df['date1']).dt.days
df['Result'] = abs((df['date2'] - df['date1']).dt.days) <=10 

print(df)
```

[**Output**]

```
      date1      date2    days  Result
0 2021-08-13 2021-08-21     8    True
1 2021-08-19 2021-08-30    11   False
2 2021-08-13 2021-08-23    10    True
3 2021-08-23 2021-08-14    -9    True
4 2021-08-30 2021-08-13   -17   False
```

Comment: Excellent solution!